# Why is Monte Carlo integration randomly sampled?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, stochastic-integrals, monte-carlo

As I understand, Monte Carlo integration uses stochastic sampling to sample points.

Obviously, you would need many samples to reach an accurate result, but why does this process have to be random?

Would using a symmetrical grid of very dense samples (e.g. a 1 million by 1 million grid) achieve the same goal?

Are there any benefits to random sampling?

Comment: Yes, using a symmetrical grid would be a solution also. But it's very very very time consuming to operate on a million times a million points, even on a powerful computer.

Comment: So how is random sampling faster?

Comment: Because you need much fewer points. And due to the random nature of the process, the answer will still be relatively reliable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the math behind why there are fewer samples needed? Does it have anything to do with convergence?

Comment: Monte-Carlo with $N$ points has an error of $O(1/\sqrt{N})$. Sampling over a grid in $d$ dimensions of $n$ sample coordinates per dimension gives a total of $N=n^d$ points. Thus you would need an integration method with error order $d/2$ to beat Monte-Carlo. Low-discrepancy sequences, also called quasi-random or sub-random, provide a Monte-Carlo error of even $O(1/N)$ which makes beating it with grid-sampling even harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be completely random. In fact, using semirandom sample points is an active area of research. For instance the [Latin Hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_hypercube_sampling) or [Sobol' sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence).

The reason it often *is* random is that nonrandom sample points can magnify certain biases present in the function to be estimated. And also, of course, because it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to revisit this question to provide what I feel is a more intuitive explanation of why a randomly sampled algorithm is faster at providing a result.

Look at the two image below. Both do not show the complete, full quality image. They are both approximations of the actual image (which is analogous to the graph of some function).

You can view the blurred image as the randomly sampled one and the mostly black image as the uniformly distributed one. The **same** number of sample points can be used for computing both of the below images.

However, by randomly sampling those few points, we can get an idea of what we are approximating **faster**. The same cannot be said of the uniformly distributed image, where all the samples were "spent" showing, in full detail, only a small portion of the overall image. *I believe this is why, intuitively, random sampling can give us a better result.*

[image: Dog_Blurred]

[image]

Comment: In the second case you would in a realistic implementation sample over an equally spaced grid and get a similar image to the first one. The effect of Monte-Carlo is only noticeable in high dimensions, I do not think that you can get striking and realistic examples in two dimensions.